# Starting Spring boot REST controller in two ports

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Is there a way to have two rest controller running on two different ports from one spring boot application ?

Say for example Controller_A running in http://localhost:8080 and Controller_B running in http://localhost:9090 in one SpringBoot main Application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is actually creating two application properties;

***app-A.properties***

```
server.port=8080
```

***app-B.properties***

```
server.port=9090
```

And then in your controllers, put annotation like below;

```
@Profile("A")
public class ControllerA {
   ...
}

@Profile("B")
public class ControllerB {
   ...
}
```

Finally you need to launch your application twice with following settings;

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=A awesomeSpringApp.jar
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=B awesomeSpringApp.jar
```

Comment: My application must not be started two times . Is there any possible way to do it , I can have my other controller in test folder too .

Comment: There is another long way,  take a look at this tutorial;  bit.ly/2SKBYgR